# Dynamic Presentation of Label as per the Data coming from web services Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am trying to render list of information inside a frame the information which comes up from database is in two parts ie "Description" : "Value" 
so the row inside list make i group of description and value and some may not have

so can anyone help me how can i add the label to grid or stack as per the data which i get from my services because it could be 3 sometimes and it could be 5 sometime and creating label and binding them would be a static job

Comment: You can use stacklayout and inside that put all labels and set visibility according to the data.

Comment: You need to design this from c# instead of xaml, to achieve this.

Comment: What you can do is Take one Stack Layout[Parent layout] and after that as per your response, add child element in that layout as per your requirement.

Comment: @MShah i am trying to do that

Comment: @AditKothari i need to make it dynamic so i can get less number of data or i can get more number of label how would i hide and show when i wont even know how many number of labels i would be getting\

Comment: @MShah do have anything which i can refer to, to achieve the current solution

Comment: @RonakShethia you can refer this for designing, the accepted answer has that implementation that how you can add Label in stack layout which is in List view, from C#, you just need to use `For loop` to add child in stack layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192092/discussion-between-mshah-and-ronak-shethia).

Comment: @RonakShethia use can refer from this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26897/loop-through-stacklayouts-and-children

Comment: @MShah could u please have a look at my edit code

Comment: @AditKothari could u please have look to my edited code

Answer (score 2):

There is a very clean answer if you can use xamarin forms3.5 or greater, BindableLayout.

Xaml file

```
<ListView
            x:Name="listView"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Category}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Blue" />
                            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding users}">
                                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In my ViewModel

```
public class DynamicSwitchViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        public DynamicSwitchViewModel(ContentPage view):base(view)
        {
            ObservableCollection<User> users1 = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            users1.Add(new User() { Name = "karan3" });
            users1.Add(new User() { Name = "karan4" });
            users1.Add(new User() { Name = "karan5" });
            ObservableCollection<User> users2 = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            users2.Add(new User() { Name = "karan1" });
            users2.Add(new User() { Name = "karan2" });
            users2.Add(new User() { Name = "karan3" });
            users2.Add(new User() { Name = "karan4" });
            users2.Add(new User() { Name = "karan5" });
            ObservableCollection<User> users3 = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            users3.Add(new User() { Name = "karan1" });
            users3.Add(new User() { Name = "karan2" });
            users3.Add(new User() { Name = "karan3" });
            Category = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
            Category.Add(new Category() { Name = "1",users=users1 });
            Category.Add(new Category() { Name = "2",users=users2 });
            Category.Add(new Category() { Name = "3",users=users3 });


        }
        private ObservableCollection<Category> category;
        public ObservableCollection<Category> Category
        {
            get { return category; }
            set { SetProperty(ref category, value); }
        }

    }
    public class Category
    {
        public  ObservableCollection<User> users { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: Output:]

Comment: i tried the same but the out put is same i am facing same issue i get duplicate values in other rows also

Comment: it is not duplicated i added same values in all rows. Please check my observable collections users1,users2 and users3. All contain same strings.

Comment: if you can create a sample i can help you with that.

Comment: just add the data to group 1 I.E karan 1, karan 2, karan 3, karan 4, karan 5 and leave other groups empty dont add any data

Comment: it is working as expected even after removing data from group 2 and 3. Here is the screenshot https://imgur.com/qalpmHY