# How to bind multiple rows and columns to the list view?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

my list view containing grid, i need to bind dynamically a multiple rows and columns inside the grid.

(Grid.Row and Grid.column values are getting from the list view)

This is my xaml code:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="xxxx" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                   <Image Source = {Binding image} Grid.Row = {Binding rowNo} Grid.Column = {Binding columnNo}/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is my cs:

```cs
new item { image = "x.png", rowNo = "1", columnNo = "0"}
```

By using this im getting an output 
(For Example: Grid.row =2 Grid.column =2 
My output was :

```
        1         
             1     
        1
             1
```

Im getting it as a 4 line instead of getting it in a 2 lines)

how to resolve this???

Comment: each row of your ListView will contain a Grid - I don't think that's what you want?  If you just want a single grid look into using a Bindable Layout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758023/dynamic-presentation-of-label-as-per-the-data-coming-from-web-services-xamarin-f.  Take a look if it is something you are looking for. Or explain it with some real time example so people can see what you want.

Comment: I want to bind multiple rows and columns in single grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can get this done with the `VerticalGrid` option from the `CollectionView` control.
Do note that the CollectionView is still in Preview, but will land be RTM in XF 4.0 ( is current estimate ).
Still, it can already be used.

Details are mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

When you create your CollectionView, you can specify how many columns it should use like so:

```
CollectionView collectionView = new CollectionView
{
    ...
    ItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(2, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical)
};
```

This will render a 2 column layout.
See if this fits your needs.